# How can I force spring-saml-extension to re-authenticate everytime?

Tags: adfs2.0, spring-saml

I recently ran successfully the spring-saml-sample working with ADFS 2.0.

However I noticed that ADFS only ask me once my user/pass, and then I can enter as many times I want but always with the same user (even when I did a global logout).

Is seems there is a cookie or something stored locally that is sent to ADFS.

What if I want to authenticate with a different user on the same machine? How can I configure saml-extension in order to force authentication again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SAML contains a mechanism for forcing IDP to re-authenticate user called forced authentication. You can enable it by setting flag `forceAuthn` in `WebSSOProfileOptions` to true. You can find more details on setting this in the [Spring SAML manual, chapter 9.2.1](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-sso-process-sp-init).

Comment: Thanks again Vlad. There's only a little thing I found on docs. Attribute  `forceAuthn` is actually `forceAuthN`. At least is how it worked for me. May be I have an older version of saml-extension.

Comment: Hummm...@Vladimír-Schäfer This is strange. WebSSO profile is defined as:
`<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
    <property name="includeScoping" value="false" />
    <property name="forceAuthN" value="true" />
    <property name="passive" value="false" />
   </bean>`  
However it has not effect.

Comment: Then I'm afraid ADFS doesn't support this SAML feature. Or perhaps you're using HTTP-Basic authentication on ADFS side? If that is the case you will need to restart browser to re-authenticate, this is a limitation of HTTP-Basic and there's no workaround afaik.

Comment: ADFS has traditionally always supported ForceAuthn. If it doesn't work then check your update and hotfix levels (or report a bug).

Comment: Later I realized that this comment could be interpreted as contradicting Vladimir. That was not the intention. ForceAuthn for ADFS means: do not use the cookie identity, do real authentication. The real authentication can be totally invisible (for the user) depending on many things.

Comment: Yep, I can see how ADFS gets (somehow) previously entered.

Comment: Vladimir, I'm using Windows Authentication without Extended. I guess ADFS saves something about the client-machine and this is how it re-authenticate for me.

Comment: I finally got it.  `forceAuthn` flag only works when adfs/ls is configured to authenticate with Form Auth instead of Windows Auth.

Comment: On http://www.richardawilson.com/2010/10/adfs-20-login-page.html I foud how to configure adfs/iis.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Vladimir's answer, if you are able to continue login even after global logout has been done, you should check that as well. After global logout all SP and IDP sessions should be deleted and so ideally you should not be able to use the site.

Comment: Also, please be aware that some IDPs may not support the flag if they are not fully compliant with the spec.

Comment: I think that´s happening with adfs 2.0. I will investigate if I can  delete cookies or something like that.  
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Rob, did you get it working? in our case, ADFS removes the cookies for first time. But when user relogins and then logs out, then it is not clearing the cookies, also it stays on the ADFS logout page instead of redirecting the user to application.