# Spring Security Saml forceAuthn specific requests

Tags: spring, security, saml

Is there a way in spring security Saml to set forceAuthn=true based on request parameters.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27833355/2587871 override the value based on the request ?

Basically as a Service provide we work with both Oauth and SAML idp. So when the client send prompt=login we want to honor it in SAML side too.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to implement this using the following option.

1. Extend SAMLEntryPoint
2. Override getProfileOptions

   ```
   WebSSOProfileOptions webProfile = super.getProfileOptions(context, exception);
   if(prompt=login){
     webProfile.setForceAuthN(true);
   }
   return webProfile;
   ```